# Exception testing

Tags: java, exception, junit

I am trying to write a test to check the method is throwing an IllegalArgumentException. To do that I wrote a simple test code but it gives error.

Method is a constructor by the way.

```
public Range(double lower, double upper) {
        if (lower > upper) {
            String msg = "Range(double, double): require lower (" + lower 
                + ") <= upper (" + upper + ").";
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(msg);
        }
        this.lower = lower;
        this.upper = upper;
    }
```

Test code

```
    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testConstructor(){
        
        new Range(5,-2);
        
    }
```

What I got is

Í java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Range(double, double): require lower (5.0) <= upper (-2.0).

as expected. But why Junit behaves like it is an error, even if I added  `@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)` before the test?

Comment: What  is the error you are getting?

Comment: What version of JUnit you're using?

Comment: @dhanushkac java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Range(double, double): require lower (5.0) <= upper (-2.0). Test does not pass its color red instead green

Comment: @Maroun I am using Junit with 4.10 version